# Insert array of photos in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this input

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]"> 

for($j=0; $j < count($files['infos']); $j++){

            $photo[$j] = $files->file('photos[]');

            if (count($photo[$j]) > 0) {
                $file_storage = Storage::disk('local')->put('images/photos', $photo[$j], 'public');
            }
}
```

After that I got this error

> file_put_contents(/usr/local/www/doc_test/public/images/photos):
>   failed to open stream: Is a directory

**EDIT**

```
var_dump($photo[$j])

array(2) { [0]=> object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#378 (8) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(11) "1-slide.png" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(9) "image/png" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(716589) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["hashName":protected]=> NULL ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpdqpVKO" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phpdqpVKO" } [1]=> object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#386 (8) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(11) "4-slide.png" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(9) "image/png" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(1699553) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["hashName":protected]=> NULL ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(14) "/tmp/phphhvZUI" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phphhvZUI" } }
```

Comment: `file_put_contents()` expects a file name, you're giving it a directory name.

Comment: Understand your error. You're not defining the actual file, only a directory.

Comment: I understand but I don't know how to fix it...i've comed with a var_dump of the variable..what should I  do to fix..the problem?

Comment: Try this >put('images/photos/'.$photo[$j], public)

Comment: I've tried..and I got this error: Array to string conversion

Comment: for($j=0; $j < count($files['infos']); $j++){

            $photo = $files->file('photos[]');

            if (!is_null($photo)) {
                $file_storage = Storage::disk('local')->put('images/photos/'. $photo, 'public');
            }
}

Comment: in your approach public folder have to be writable so `chmod -R 665 public`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your blade looks like, but you can use this for file upload:

```
{{ Form::open(array('files'=>'true', 'action' => 'Controller@upload') ) }}
{{ Form::file('photos[], ['multiple' => 'multiple']);
{{ Form::submit('upload') }}                            
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Your controller method 'upload' should contain this:

```
public function upload( Request $request ) {
  $this->validate( request(), [
    'file' => 'required'
  ]);

  foreach ( $request->photos as $photo ) {
    // use whatever u need 
    dump( $photo );
  }
}
```

Remember that u need to use a filename for storing...

Check this website: http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/

Answer (score 0):

ok, i see now:

```
for($j=0; $j < count($files['infos']); $j++){

        $photo[$j] = $files->file('photos[]');

        if (count($photo[$j]) > 0) {
            $file_storage = Storage::disk('local')->put('images/photos/'.str_random(6).'.jpg', $photo[$j], 'public');
        }
}
```